# Can I marry non-EU Citizen as EU-citizen in the UK?

Tags: eu-citizens, uk-visa, marriage

I am Eu citizen working in UK and would like to marry a girl non-Eu living in Indonesia. Is it possible for her to come in the UK and marry here and then stay in the UK.

What documents we need and how long it take ?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes.

In practice, the Home Office will be very doubtful that there is a genuine relationship between the two of you, and the marriage is not just for the purpose of her being able to enter the UK. You will most likely both be asked to give convincing evidence that there is a genuine relationship. Getting married just to allow a person to enter the UK is actually a crime.

Comment: This answer feels overly judgmental to me. Maybe you could give some more concrete explanation of the process.

Comment: @MJeffryes I disagree.  The *Home Office* may be very judgemental, but I think gnasher is just accurately describing the situation.  (I agree that some more details about how one goes about demonstrating a genuine relationship would be good.)